# Pin version of a 3rd party crate dependency

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a crate that has several dependencies that use one common dependency, same as the root project. An intersecting range, though.

I.e.,:

```
[dependencies]
bitcoin="0.28"
hdpath="0.6" <- this one depends on `>=0.27`
hwkey="0.1" <- this one depends on `=0.28`
```

And the current latest version is `bitcoin:0.29.2`

The current `Cargo.lock` file contains `bitcoin:0.28.1` so it all works for all of the deps and compiles fine.

But if I try to publish the crate there is no way to enforce it using the version from `Cargo.lock` and it tries to use two different version of `bitcoin`. The latest `0.29.2` for `hdpath` because it allows any version, and `0.28.1` for other parts because they are not compatible with the latest one.

That obviously doesn't work because it produces incompatible data types.

Is there any way to force Cargo to disable such an upgrade and use version from the lock file?